# Phonegap (3.0.0) debugging

Tags: debugging, cordova, weinre

I have small issues with debugging Phonegap application.

What I know:

I can upload application data to build.phonegap.com, build it, download application to phone and then use debug.build.phonegap.com to debug application, that's fine. That works for me.

What I want:

I would like to build phonegap application locally using Phonegap 3.0.0 CLI and Android SDK ("phonegap local run android") and then use weinre debug server at debug.build.phonegap.com. Everything works fine except I can't see it in debug.build.phonegap.com.

Why I want it:

It takes too much time to upload data, build it, download back and run. Even when I can use phonegap CLI ("phonegap remote build android"). I still have to use QR code, download it and install. Much better would be using "phonegap local run android" (which installs app to phone automatically) and then be able to use weinre debugger on debug.build.phonegap.com

Why it is not working?

I think this is not working because build scripts in build.phonegap.com are adding `<feature name="debug-server">` attribute into config.xml before building app. But I do not know how to fill it with data.

I hope this is understandable.
Thanks in advance, 
Martin

Comment: I wish someone could answer this... Did you find a solution?

Comment: If you have an Android KitKat device, you can now do remote debugging with Chrome: http://10typesofpeople.tumblr.com/post/76669066010/remote-debugging-phonegap-apps-with-chrome-dev-tools

Answer (score 0):

you might have found your answer to this issue by now, but this might help someone,

Here is what you have to do,

1. In /www/index.html add the below script to the head section
   `<script src="http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#ANY_ID"></script>`
2. In /www/config.xml make sure you have allowed the domain debug.build.phonegap.com , or just add `<access origin="*" />` and later you can change it.
3. Open the link http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#ANY_ID in a webkit browser that is "chrome" or "safari" (not sure why, but it didn't work in other)
4. Run your phonegap build locally on emulator or device in debug mode.

Once the build is deployed you can see your device appears under the "targets" section in green(in your browser).

I have used phonegap 3.1.0 and android 4.0 device for this and it works well, so this might work for you.

Thanks